# The f_gets function reads one byte less than I specified

Tags: usb, stm32

I specify in the `f_gets` function that 6 bytes should be read, but the `f_gets` function reads only 5 bytes.

A USB drive is connected to the [STM32F407VGT6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f405rg.pdf), and a text file is located on this USB drive.

The text file with the text `123456` is located on the USB drive.
I read the contents of the text file using the `f_gets` function.

```
char arr[10]={0};
f_gets(arr,6,&USBHFile);
```

As a result, only 5 bytes are read, and not 6 bytes as I indicated.
In this case, these characters are read `12345`

If I try to read only one byte, then nothing is read at all

```
char arr[10]={0};
f_gets(arr,1,&USBHFile);
```

Why is this happening?
Don't confuse the `f_gets` function with the `fgets` function.

Comment: Per [documentation](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/gets.html): _"The read operation continues until a '\n' is stored, reached end of the file or **the buffer is filled with len - 1 characters.** The read string is terminated with a '\0'."_ - You need an extra byte for the null terminator. This is exactly the same as `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code did exactly what you asked it to do: it reads a **string** of 6 characters, the characters being 1 2 3 4 5 \0. It didn't read 6 characters, it created a string of length 6. The difference being a null-termination.

I take it, what you intend to do is to read 6 bytes from the file. But the function you use reads **not character sequences, but strings**. In other words, whatever result that function produces (if it's not an error), the last character it returns will be a zero byte. This null-termination character counts towards requested string length. Null-terminator is a common source of headache in situations like this.

So if you want to read a string of 6 actual characters, you need to request a string of length 7, the 7th character will be null-termination. Even if the file contains 6 characters, there is at the very least an end of file character in there as well, so don't worry, you won't read past the end of file.

I suggest you fill up your read buffer with a predefined value that would stand out, such as all 0xEE, and then read into it and see how many of those bytes were actually overwritten. When you init-fill your buffer with zeroes, you won't know about the null-termination byte (a zero overwrote a zero). This is a handy approach to make sure buffers (or other memory regions of interest) behave the way you expect them to behave.